# Convert four digit year values to class Date

Tags: r, date

I've an integer column in my dataset which has four digit year values, like:

```
 c(2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2005)
```

I try to convert the four digit year to class `Date` using `as.Date`:

```
year <- as.Date(as.character(data_file$evtYear), format = "%Y")
```

But the output is:

```
"2001-05-15" "2002-05-15" "2002-05-15" "2002-05-15" "2003-05-15" "2005-05-15"
```

This is giving the wrong output. It's giving two year values in one date (both 2001 and also 15).

I just want the convert my four digit year part from the original data to 'Year' as class `Date`. Expected out put is simply:

```
2001 2002 2002 2002 2003 2005
```

But their class should be of `Date` type.

How to achieve this in R?

Comment: `Date` type in R is always a combination of year, month and day (not necessarily in this order). You cannot have a `Date` type with only the year.

Comment: @Pascal So does that mean I can't have a four digit number (2001) in my data whose class is of Date type??

Comment: You can't have that without the month and day.  BTW, why do you need this in 'Date' class with just Year?

Comment: Strictly, a year is not a date.

Comment: @akrun I'm jsut a beginner in R. I'm doing some Data Preprocessing work and there is this column with only year values.. It's of integer type. I thought I should convert it to date format so as not to have any issues later on. That is all. But now looking at all the opinions here, it sounds like integer is ok. What say?

Comment: I use the lubridate library for everything to do with dates even when it is not strictly necessary. It is just easier.

Comment: Yes, if you need just the year, an integer value is the best.

Comment: You can still turn the year into a `Date`, as you did, with the same reference (for example, the 15th of each month). Then perform any calculation. And at the end, turn your `Date` to a year value.

Comment: @nicola Thank you so much for confirming.

Comment: Thanks, all, for the comments.. It has been very helpful to know something new in R.

Answer (score 41):

As already recognized by the OP, a year alone does not make up a valid date because month and day are not specified.

However, some date and date-time conversion functions, e.g., `ymd()`, `parse_date_time()`, in the `lubridate` package recognize a parameter `truncated` to allow for parsing of incomplete dates:

```
yrs <- c(2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2005)
lubridate::ymd(yrs, truncated = 2L)
```

> ```
> [1] "2001-01-01" "2002-01-01" "2002-01-01" "2002-01-01" "2003-01-01" "2005-01-01"
> ```

The years have been completed by 1st of January to make a valid date. The result is of class `Date`.

Answer (score 38):

Based on the comments it turned out that the person asking the question did not need to change a numeric year to `"Date"` class; nevertheless, the question asked how to do it so here is an answer.

Here are a few ways to create a `"Date"` class object from a 4 digit numeric year.  All use `as.Date`:

```
yrs <- c(2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2005)
```

**1) ISOdate**

```
as.Date(ISOdate(yrs, 1, 1))  # beginning of year
as.Date(ISOdate(yrs, 12, 31))  # end of year
```

This ISOdate solution is a bit tricky because it creates an intermediate POSIXct object so time zone problems could exist.   You might prefer one of the following.

**2) paste**

```
as.Date(paste(yrs, 1, 1, sep = "-")) # beginning of year
as.Date(paste(yrs, 12, 31, sep = "-")) # end of year
```

**3) zoo::as.yearmon**

```
library(zoo)

as.Date(as.yearmon(yrs)) # beginning of year
as.Date(as.yearmon(yrs) + 11/12, frac = 1) # end of year
```

**Note:**  If `y` is the result for any of the above then `format(y, "%Y")` gives the character year and `as.numeric(format(y, "%Y"))` gives the numeric year.

Answer (score 12):

You can do:

```
library(lubridate)
yrs <- c(2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2005)
yr <- as.Date(as.character(yrs), format = "%Y")
y <- year(yr)
```

Output:

```
2001 2002 2002 2002 2003 2005
```

Comment: `lubridate::year()` returns the year element of a date-time object as a decimal number. So, `y` is identical to `yrs`. A valid date always identifies a particular day, e.g., by giving year, month, and date. `help("as.Date")` says: *If the date string does not specify the date completely, the returned answer may be system-specific. The most common behaviour is to assume that a missing year, month or day is the current one.* So, the result depends on when the statement is executed leading to random results. E.g., on my system (at the time of writing), `yr` is `2001-01-28`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A lubridate answer:

```
library(lubridate)
year <- ymd(sprintf("%d-01-01",data_file$evtYear))
```

Comment: Sorry this wasn't giving me the expected output. But I just realized from others' comments that my expected output is not a valid one: simply a four digit year value can't be of Date type.. Anyways, thank you so much for pointing out the lubridate package. Will look into it when the time comes.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing it can make sense to use the date format  anyway and get practice using the lubridate library. For example if you need to calculate the distance between dates, or in-between dates. If you are going to analyze data you are going to need to get good at manipulating dates and times as a large percentage of data is date related.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed in 2 steps with `as.Date()`.

1. Convert the year into a date
2. Extract the year from the generated (in the first step) date

```
year <- data_file %>%
  mutate(year = as.Date(ISOdate(evtYear, 1, 1)) , #first, convert the year into a date
         year = format(year,'%Y'))                #second, extract the year from the date
```