# Year column to time series

Tags: r, date

OK, this should be really simple but I'm not 'getting it.' I have a data frame with a column "Year" that I want to convert to a time series, but the format is tripping me up. How do I convert the "Year" value to a date, with the actual date being the end of each respective year (e.g. 2015 -> December 31st 2015)?

```
  Year   Production
1 1900     38400000
2 1901     43400000
3 1902     49000000
4 1903     44100000
5 1904     49800000
```

Goal is to get this to a time series data frame. (e.g. xts)

It is not quite the same as a previous question that converted a vector of years to dates. ["Convert four digit year values to date type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255833/convert-four-digit-year-values-to-a-date-type). Goal is to index the data by date, converting it to xts or similar object.

Edited:
This was the final solution:

```
df <- xts(x = df_original, order.by = as.Date(paste0(df_original[,1], "-12-31")))
```

whereby the "[,1]" indicates the first column of the original data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each full date to be 31 December, you could use `paste` along with `as.Date` to cast to a date:

```
df$date <- as.Date(paste0(df$Year, "-12-31"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tim Biegeleisen's answer, I will just add another way

```
df$final_date <- as.Date(ISOdate(df$Year, 12, 31))
```

Comment: That works. It converts the four digit year to a date and adds a new column. How would you then convert the df$final_date to an index and xts object. (or other time series object)?