# how to convert numeric only year in Date in R?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a data-frame with column year numeric, but i would like to convert it in year date.

my data-frame

```
library(tidyverse)
    
date2<-c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001')
name<-c('A','B','C')
    
df<-data.frame(date2,name)
```

but when I perform the command `mutate`:

```
df2<-df%>%
  mutate(date2=dmy(date2))%>%
  mutate(Year2=year(date2))

str(df2)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date2: Date, format: "2000-01-01" "2000-08-08" "2001-03-16"
 $ name : chr  "A" "B" "C"
 $ Year2: num  2000 2000 2001
```

but I would like Year2 to be Date and not numeric.

How to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert four digit year values to class Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255833/convert-four-digit-year-values-to-class-date)

Comment: Yes that's right. But for what reason does R convert everything for the 1st of January of each year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `round_date`, [EDIT] or better `floor_date` to round to the start of the year(see comment & answer below):

```
library(lubridate)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(date2 = dmy(date2)) %>%
  mutate(year_internal = round_date(date2,'year')) %>%
  mutate(year_out = format(year_internal,'%Y'))

df2 %>% select(date2, name, year_internal, year_out)

       date2 name year_internal year_out
1 2000-01-01    A    2000-01-01     2000
2 2000-08-08    B    2001-01-01     2001
3 2001-03-16    C    2001-01-01     2001
```

Comment: but how do i stay with the year?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you'd like a `Date`, this is what `round_date` returns. Now for output, you could use `format(df2$Year2,'%Y')` so that you keep a `Date` internally, but show only the `Year`

Comment: exactly. but how can I add the command format `(df2$Year2, '%Y')` to the code?

Comment: see my edit : you could select `year_internal` for output, or not and just select `year_out`

Comment: ok now it's clear to me. But the year_out output is as a character. Would R be able to interpret it as a date?

Comment: No, R won't be able to interpret it directly as a Date. You'll need for example `as.Date(df2$year_out,'%Y')` or `ymd(df2$year_out,truncated = 2)`

Comment: Hello Friend @Waldi. I discovered a problem with this solution. round_date () rounds up the correct dates! However, I found out that some dates in 2005, for example, were rounded up to 2006. Unfortunately, I still haven't been able to solve it, because my analysis was problematic

Comment: eu encontri `floor_date()` que é melhor para o meu caso

Comment: @wesley, thanks for your feedback : I knew this difference but didn't think about its consequences in case of year rounding.

Answer (score 1):

I verified that `round_date()` brings problems because it leases dates from the year 2000 to 2001, this can be a problem in the statistics.

Based on another post I found the `floor_date()` that rounds up for the same year.

```
date2<-c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001')
name<-c('A','B','C')

df<-data.frame(date2,name)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(date2 = dmy(date2)) %>%
  mutate(year_date = floor_date(date2,'year'))

df2
```

see that 200-08-08 is now rounded up to the year 2000

```
date2<date> name<chr> year_date<date>
2000-01-01  A   2000-01-01      
2000-08-08  B   2000-01-01      
2001-03-16  C   2001-01-01
```

Comment: This might be an English-language issue, but I would describe what `floor_date()` does as rounding **down**, not up ...