# Rounding dates with round_date() in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I try convert date format yyyymmdd in yyyy only in R.
In [how to convert numeric only year in Date in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514516/how-to-convert-numeric-only-year-in-date-in-r) presented a very interesting answer, as it managed to make R understand to convert an 8-digit entry (yyyymmdd) as a 4-digit year year (yyyy) in the lubricated package, this is very good for me.

in old code i used `round_date()` for it:

```
   date2<-c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001','25/12/2000','29/02/2000')
    name<-c('A','B','C','D','E')
    
    df<-data.frame(date2,name)
    
    df2 <- df %>%
      mutate(date2 = dmy(date2)) %>%
      mutate(year_date = round_date(date2,'year'))
    
    df2
    str(df2)

date2<date> name<chr> year_date <date>
2000-01-01    A         2000-01-01      
2000-08-08    B         2001-01-01      
2001-03-16    C         2001-01-01      
2000-12-25    D         2001-01-01      
2000-02-29    E         2000-01-01
```

But I started to have problems with my statistical analysis when discovering for example that a date 2000-08-08 was rounded up to the year 2001-01-01, instead of 2001-01-01 as I expected.

This is a very big problem for me, since information that belongs to the year 2005 has been moved to the year 2006, considering that I have more than 1400 rows in my database.

I noticed that dates after the middle of the year (after June) are rounded up to the next year, this is very bad.

How do I round a 2000-08-08 date to just 2000 instead of 2001?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't this (simpler, also only base R) operation do what you want?

```
> date2 <- c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001','25/12/2000','29/02/2000')
> dd <- as.Date(date2, "%d/%m/%Y")
> yd <- format(dd, "%Y-01-01")
> dt <- as.Date(yd)
> D <- data.frame(date2=date2, date=dd, y=yd, d=dt)
> D
       date2       date          y          d   
1 01/01/2000 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
2 08/08/2000 2000-08-08 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
3 16/03/2001 2001-03-16 2001-01-01 2001-01-01
4 25/12/2000 2000-12-25 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
5 29/02/2000 2000-02-29 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
>
```

In essence we just extract the year component from the (parsed as date) `Date` object and append `-01-01`.

*Edit:* There are also `trunc()` operations for `Date` and `Datetime` objects.  Oddly, truncation for years only works for `Datetime` (see the help page for `trunc.Date` for more) so this works too:

```
> as.Date(trunc(as.POSIXlt(dd), "years"))
[1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2001-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01"
>
```

*Edit 2:*  We can use that last step in a cleaner / simpler solution in a `data.frame` with three columns for *input* data (as characters), *parse* data as a proper `Date` type and the desired *truncated* year data — all using base R without further dependencies.  Of course, if you would *want* to you *could* rewrite it via the pipe and `lubridate` for the same result via slightly slower route (which only matters for "large" data).

```
> date2 <- c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001','25/12/2000','29/02/2000')
> pd <- as.Date(date2, "%d/%m/%Y")
> td <- as.Date(trunc(as.POSIXlt(pd), "years"))
> D <- data.frame(input = date2, parsed = pd, output = td)
> D
       input     parsed     output
1 01/01/2000 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
2 08/08/2000 2000-08-08 2000-01-01
3 16/03/2001 2001-03-16 2001-01-01
4 25/12/2000 2000-12-25 2000-01-01
5 29/02/2000 2000-02-29 2000-01-01
>
```

For a real "production" use you may not need the `data.frame` and do not need to keep the intermediate result leading to a one-liner:

```
> as.Date(trunc(as.POSIXlt( as.Date(date2, "%d/%m/%Y") ), "years"))
[1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2001-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01"
>
```

which is likely the most compact and efficient conversion you can get.

Comment: Hi, Dirk, tested `df2<-df%>%
  mutate(date2 = dmy(date2)) %>%
  mutate(year_date=format(date2, "%Y-01-01"))` is good.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Using _typed_ representation makes for safer programming, so I recommend converting to `Date` sooner.  You can still use whatever add-on functions from whatever add-on packages you like, but they do use the underlying base R types.  They are fundamental building blocks -- and as you can see you can mix and match.

Comment: Your answer is good, as it solves not only this problem others I have here. But the output `y` in the data frame` D` is in the format `<chr>`. I would need it to be in the `<date>`> format. I like to use R-base, but I see that this is a problem when it comes to dates. Greetings.

Comment: Because it is in standard ISO 8601 Form you can just run `as.Date() ` on it.

Comment: See the edit: you can just do `trunc(dd, "years")` but (oddly) need to go to `Datetime` and then back to `Date`.

Comment: I agree with Dirk and always recommend to use **ISO 8601** format. It is **the international standard** and makes live easier. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Thanks @tpetzoldt -- I just tweeted about the three nice answers by you, me and Ben here and tried to 'link' to you but couldn't: https://twitter.com/eddelbuettel/status/1394279537215692802. Another time...

Comment: I now filed a bug report on the "`trunc.Date` does not truncate to months or years" behaviour: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18099

Comment: Dear Dirk, looking more calmly, your answer is very good, as it generates `<date>`, much more suitable for a `ggplot` for example. I managed to do it using the pipe operator `%>%`. The operator is better for me, as I don't need to create intermediate data.frames. code: `df<-data.frame(date2,name)%>%
  mutate(date3=as.Date(date2, "%d/%m/%Y"))%>%
  mutate(year_date=as.Date(trunc(as.POSIXlt(date3), "years")))`

Comment: Using `trunc.Date` or `floor_date ()` what would be the advantage of each other? as the answer from @tpetzoldt also solves my problem

Comment: Some people, myself  included, value to longevity, support, robustness, and sparsity  of relying on base R and just a few other packages.  Other people (you?) prefer add-on packages, here `lubridate`, and don't mind the dependency tail.  And as they say, you can't debate taste or style but I think I could show easily that my approach will be faster for lots of dates.  For just a few (hundred, even thousand) it may not matter so much. And the end of the day, your call!

Comment: Didn't see your earlier comment.  I think you're wrong there -- I used the data frame mostly just for exposition.  The use of subsequent plotting does not require a pipe -- recall that `ggplot2` does not even use `magrittr`.  You could, if you wanted to, just transform `date2` in one line as my last edit a few hours ago shows.   But at the end of the day I think _all three_ answers here help you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want just the year (and not the date corresponding to the first day of the year) you can use `lubridate::year()`.

```r
df %>% mutate(across(date2,dmy),
              year_date=year(date2))
```

If you do want the first day of the year then `floor_date()` will do the trick.

```r
df %>% mutate(across(date2,dmy),
               year_date=floor_date(date2,"year"))
```

or if you only need the truncated date you could go directly to `mutate(year_date=floor_date(dmy(date2)))`

In base R, `year()` would be `format(date2, "%Y")`, as shown in @DirkEddelbuettel's answer.

Comment: hi, Ben this solution solves part of the problem, but note that when using `year()` the result does not return a date, but a `<dbl>` instead of a `<date>`.

Comment: Yes, it depends what you want. If (as I tried to state in my answer) you want a date, you need to use `floor_date()` (as in the second part of my answer, and @tpetzoldt's answer)

Answer (score 3):

If you consult the `round_date`help page, you will also see `floor_date`:

```
library("lubridate")
library("dplyr")

date2 <- c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001','25/12/2000','29/02/2000')
name <- c('A','B','C','D','E')

df <- data.frame(date2,name)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(date2 = dmy(date2)) %>%
  mutate(year_date = floor_date(date2,'year'))

df2
```

Comment: Hello tpetzoldt, in the case `floor_date ()` always rounds to January 1st of each year?

Comment: See help page: "`floor_date()` takes a date-time object and rounds it down to the nearest boundary of the specified time unit" and: "`unit` a character string specifying a time unit or a multiple of a unit to be rounded to ..."